# monitor disk writes by directory

Tags: ubuntu, disk-usage, monitoring

I am trying to track where excessive disk writes are coming from whether by mail coming in, db writes, logs or another source.  There are about 75 accounts on the server, some active and some not.

Is there any type of disk I/O command I can execute which will specify the DIRECTORY(ies) to which disk writes are happening?  If it's a db write, I would expect I'd see it come through on `/var/lib/mysql/that_database_name`

-- ADDITION --

I vaguely recall about 2 years ago I executed some command that was similar to a `tail -f` where I was watching the writes come through, and I *think* that specified the folder.  If I was tailing a disk write log (if such a thing exists), then it's location or its access in this format would accomplish what I am wanting to.

Comment: Disk writes are done by `inode`, not by directory. Reversing `indode`s to filenames is hard, certainly not something you can do in real time. It's probably more feasible to monitor what processes do the writes.

Comment: I don't need to know the file names, just the `inode` to which a write has taken place.  That can give me everything I need.

Comment: I recall there was a command that had an output real-time similar to `tail -f` which listed the write event and IIRC the directory/inode

Comment: Since you're using Linux, try [iotop](http://guichaz.free.fr/iotop/).

Comment: This is not exactly like the command that I remember, or the output (though it is giving useful information).  In fact maybe I was doing a tail of a write log previously!  Any idea, if that was true, if in fact there is a write log to tail?

Answer (score 9):

You might be thinking of **fatrace**, which can monitor all writes to a filesystem, eg:

```
$ sudo fatrace -f W 
chrome(19909): W /home/meuh/.config/google-chrome/Default/Current Session
bash(2777): CW /home/meuh/.bashhistory
emacs(2100): CW /home/meuh/bin/emacs/.emacs.desktop
auditd(711): W /var/log/audit/audit.log
rsyslogd(762): W /var/log/secure
```

The `-f W` restricts output to any write operations, listing executable, pid, and file written.

Another possibility is **iosnoop** from Brendan D. Gregg's [perf-tools](https://github.com/brendangregg/perf-tools) which gives low-level info on blocks written to a disk:

```
$ sudo perf-tools-master/bin/iosnoop
Tracing block I/O. Ctrl-C to end.
COMM         PID    TYPE DEV      BLOCK        BYTES     LATms
/usr/bin/mon 31456  R    8,0      9741888      4096       2.14
/usr/bin/mon 31456  R    8,0      12904784     4096       1.43
jbd2/sda3-41 416    WS   8,0      130618232    65536      1.89
jbd2/sda3-41 416    WS   8,0      210006528    8192       1.94
<...>        288    WS   8,0      129710104    61440      1.85
<idle>       0      WS   8,0      129710224    4096       0.36
cat          32111  WS   8,0      10443000     4096       0.35
```

Another possibility, if you only want to watch a few sets of files is **inotifywait**, eg:

```
$ inotifywait -m -e modify -r /tmp
Setting up watches.  Beware: since -r was given, this may take a while!
Watches established.
/tmp/ MODIFY myfile
```

The `-r` is recursive down the given directories. This is costly to setup, and users are limited by default to 8192 watches, but you can change this in `/proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_watches`.

Comment: `fatrace` sounds what I used.  `yum update && yum install fatrace` don't recognize the package; how do I get yum to recognize the correct repo here? https://rpms.remirepo.net/rpmphp/zoom.php?rpm=fatrace

Comment: I'm using fedora 23 where `dnf` (which replaces yum) found it ok. What version do you have? You might also search [here, rpmfind](https://www.rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=fatrace&submit=Search+...&system=fedora&arch=).